# How to get the values of Json Serialize in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, json, model-view-controller

I have a PrintView Model list, inside the list item, there is another list which is Summary.
I'm using ASP.NET MVC

```
 @model CRC.Models.PrintViewModel;
 <label id="lblTotalMonthlyLoanDeduction"></label>
```

I serialize it using json

```
var obj = @Json.Serialize(Model.summary);
console.log(obj);
```

[image]

I want to get the value and put it into label.

Comment: Can't you just access the model property in the label directly? e.g. `<label>@Model.summary.TotalMonthlyLoanDeduction</label>`

Comment: im using keyvalue pair string string, it says cannot cast.

Comment: Could you show PrintViewModel class, my friend?

Comment: public class PrintViewModel
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public DateTime inquiry_date { get; set; }
        public List<PrintInquiry> entities { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> summary { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can show the data through Model.Summary.

Here is a sample.

1. Controller

   ```
    public IActionResult Index()
            {
                var model = new PrintViewModel();
                var summary = new[] {
                          new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Name","John"),
                          new KeyValuePair<string,string>("City","NY")
                        };
                model.Summary = summary;
                return View(model);
            }
   ```
2. Views

   ```
    @{
        string totalMonthlyLoan = null;
        string totalMonthlyFB = null;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in Model.Summary)
        {
            switch (item.Key)
            {
                case "TotalMonthlyLoan":
                    totalMonthlyLoan = item.Value;
                    break;
                case "TotalMonthlyFB":
                    totalMonthlyFB = item.Value;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    <label id="lblTotalMonthlyLoan">@totalMonthlyLoan</label>
    <label id="lblTotalMonthlyLoan">@totalMonthlyFB</label>
   ```

Comment: @jrdones: You're always welcome, my friend :d